# Django Rest Framework + gson : utf-8 can't decode

Tags: android, python, django, gson, django-rest-framework

I'm working with Django Rest Framework to build my API and with Android + GSON in my client side.
There is a problem with encoding when I try to send a POST with a field "country" and value "Perú". I receive the error:

```
{"detail": "JSON parse error - 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 15: invalid start byte"}
```

I changed a parameter in my post with this:

```
postRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(gson.toJson(object), HTTP.UTF_8));
```

The server doesn't return me the same error, but It throws HTTP 500 error.
Is there any way to manage it in client or server side? Which one do you recommend?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://glue-talk.com/1501/utf-8-problem-json-java-android/) can help